# Pass parameter to bash script from Python3

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have a bash script calibrate.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

rotctl -vvvvv --send-cmd-term=-1 -m 903 -r /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200 w \\0x57\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0xf9\\0x20
```

And I want to call it in Python with argument type of:

```
\\0x57\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0xf9\\0x20
```

I've tried like this, but no success.. I think that problem in backslash or hex..

```
   packet="\x57\x33\x36\x30\x30\x01\x33\x36\x30\x30\x01\xf9\x20"
   bash_cmd="./calibrate.sh " + packet
   res=subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

And changed calibrate.sh accordingly:

```
rotctl -vvvvv --send-cmd-term=-1 -m 903 -r /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200 w $1
```

Comment: I wouldn't involve the shell in this at all; `Popen("./calibrate.sh", packet, executable='/bin/bash')`. Whether `calibrate.sh` is written to correctly handle the argument it receives is another matter. Keep in mind that if the packet can contain a null byte, then you need to rewrite `calibrate.sh` considerably, because shell parameters simply *cannot* contain null bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a raw string for packet:

```
packet=r"\\0x57\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0x33\\0x36\\0x30\\0x30\\0x0a\\0xf9\\0x20"
```

That way it doesn't process any of the escape characters.